# Python struct.Struct.size returning unexpected value

Tags: python, struct

I am using Python to convert some files to a binary format, but I've run into an odd snare.

## Problem

### Code

```
import struct
s = struct.Struct('Bffffff')
print s.size
```

### Result

```
28
```

Obviously the expected size would be `25`, but it appears to be interpreting the first byte (`B`) as a 4-byte integer of some kind. It will also write out a 4-byte integer instead of a byte.

## Work-around

A work-around exists, namely separating the `B` out into a separate `struct`, like so:

### Code

```
import struct
s1 = struct.Struct('B')
s2 = struct.Struct('ffffff')
print s1.size + s2.size
```

### Result

```
25
```

Is there any explanation for this behavior?

Comment: The reason the struct is bigger than expected is that padding bytes are added to it so that the floats in the struct are properly aligned. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Comment: An alternate work-around is to place the byte field at the end of the struct: `print struct.Struct('ffffffB').size` prints 25.

Comment: The first letter is padded to 4 bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you specify any character for byte order, alignment, `struct` use native byte order, alignment(`@`); which cause padding.

By explicitly specifying byte order, you can get what you want:

```
>>> struct.Struct('!Bffffff').size  # network byte order
25
>>> struct.Struct('=Bffffff').size  # native byte order, no alignment.
25
>>> struct.Struct('>Bffffff').size  # big endian
25
>>> struct.Struct('<Bffffff').size  # little endian
25
>>> struct.Struct('@Bffffff').size  # native byte order, alignment. (+ native size)
28
```

Comment: '@' means also native **size**, which may give you a bad surprise when you copy your python code to a different computer (32 vs 64 bit)

Comment: @Thinkeye, Thank you for the information. I updated the code comment to include that information.

Answer (score 6):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment)

> Padding is only automatically added between successive structure members. No padding is added at the beginning or the end of the encoded struct.

If you test

```
>>> import struct
>>> s1 = struct.Struct('B')
>>> print s1.size
1
>>> s1 = struct.Struct('f')
>>> print s1.size
4
```

So when you add it is `25` ... But the other way round, `B` is 1 and the rest are `4` so it will be padded to make it `4` thus the answer is `28`
Consider this example

```
>>> s1 = struct.Struct('Bf')
>>> print s1.size
8
```

Again here `B` is `1` and padded `3` and `f` is `4` so finally it comes up to `8` which is as expected.

As mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment)  to override it you will have to use non-native methods

```
>>> s1 = struct.Struct('!Bf')
>>> print s1.size
5
```

> No padding is added when using non-native size and alignment, e.g. with ‘<’, ‘>’, ‘=’, and ‘!’.